# Is it okay to do an Async dispatch from within another action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, vuex

I feel like i'm encountering a race condition somewhere. This is the only part of my app where i'm dispatching an async action. Is doing the below the right way to do it? Or do I need to wrap a Promise return inside asyncActionTwo?

```
async asyncActionOne ({state, dispatch}, val) {

    const {success} = await APIService.seats.increment(val)

    if (!success) {
        return router.push({name: 'ErrorNotFound'})
    }

    await dispatch('asyncActionTwo')
},
async asyncActionTwo ({commit}) {
    const {id, pwd} = router.history.current.params
    if (!(id && pwd)) {
        console.error(`No credentials: id: ${id}, pwd: ${pwd}`)
        return router.push({name: 'ErrorNotFound'})
    }
    const response = await APIService.cart.getPrice({id, pwd})
    const {success, previewResult} = response

    if (!success || !previewResult) {
        console.error('No Preview Result --> ', previewResult)
        return router.push({name: 'ErrorNotFound'})
    }

    commit('setPriceData', previewResult.invoices[0])

    return response
},
```

Comment: does `asyncActionOne` need to `return` something if `success` is `true`?

Comment: what do you mean feel ... racecondition - vuex implements flux pattern

Comment: asyncActionOne doesn't return anything if `success` is `true`. It'll just call `asyncActionTwo` if `success` is `true` to recalculate prices.

Will that cause me to have issues in my component when I do `await asyncActionOne()` since it's not returning anything? Which is making me think that may be the issue because it's not returning any promise right?

Comment: it is returning Promise<undefined | router.push> - not returning feels like stopping execution ... i don´t see any race condition - especially as you await the response within those actions